# How to display world daylight map?

Tags: 11.04, time, indicator

I really liked the world map with daylight time displayed on it, when you click on date/time tray icon.

It appeared right bellow the calendar.

How do I get it back in unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to Ted Gould, the indicator-datetime author about this:

> It would be easier to do as a patch next release.  We're going to make adding custom dbusmenu items easier. We still need to work out the details, but basically we're looking to have a set of items that can be loaded by the panel service instead of having them hard coded in the indicator .so's
>
> This makes it so that you can build them and test them reasonably on their own. But also so that app developers could make them, install them in the right directory, and then use them.
>
> Yeah, there's still a lot of details to work out.  But I'm hoping to land that in O.

So long story short, Ted is looking for someone to make this happen, and unfortunately we don't have anything for 11.04. The [code is here](https://launchpad.net/indicator-datetime) and if you can find someone to [get involved](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/) that would be even better. I'd be more than happy to point a contributor to the right resources if someone is interested.